# React component structure and passing state upward

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few components that each contain inputs, and on the main component I have a button that will send that information all at once to the server. The problem is that the main component that has the button doesn't have the input content of the child components.

In the past I've passed down a method that would send the content back up into the state, but is there an easier less painful way of doing it? It just feels like an odd way of doing that.

Here's a short example of what I have and what I mean.

Main component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';

import Message from './Message';


class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { test: '' };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mainFrame">
        <h2>Program</h2>
        <Message />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

And the message component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Input from 'react-toolbox/lib/input';

class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { message: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ message: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Input
        type="text"
        label="Message"
        name="name"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Message;
```

Comment: that's why [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) exist.

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez, still, redux if for large complex applications. for smaller ones, callbacks are sufficient.

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez I would say redux is much more painfull because here only requirement is to collect the value of input field.

Comment: @Milos the way you are doing is right and in fact this is how react works and is a recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes. You can try using refs. Add a `ref` to `Message` component, and you will be able to access the child component's methods, state and everything. But thats not the conventional way, people generally use `callbacks`, as you mentioned earlier.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';

import Message from './Message';


class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { test: '' };
  }
   
  clickHandler () {
    let childState = this.refs.comp1.state //returns the child's state. not prefered.
    let childValue = this.refs.comp1.getValue(); // calling a method that returns the child's value
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mainFrame">
        <h2>Program</h2>
        <Message ref="comp1"/>
        <Button onClick={this.clickHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Input from 'react-toolbox/lib/input';

class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { message: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ message: value });
  }
  
  getValue () {
    return this.state.message;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Input
        type="text"
        label="Message"
        name="name"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Message;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing what is suggested [in docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so it's a good way.

> I have a button that will send that information all at once to the server

I assume then it might be `form` you can use. If so you can just handle `onSubmit` event and create FormData object containing all nested input field names with their values (even in children components). No need for callbacks then.

```
handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = e.currentTarget;
  const formData = new FormData(form); // send it as a body of your request

  // form data object will contain key value pairs corresponding to input `name`s and their values.    
}
```

[checkout Retrieving a FormData object from an HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)